# Designing of an audio amplifier using LM386 and a preamplifier

Tags: audio, mains, preamp, lm386, electret

This is the circuit . But i am still getting acoustic howling. What can I do to prevent it dynamically. Also I want to increase the sensitivity to the extent that when I rub my fingers in front of the electret mic the speaker should be able to play it . when I cover the speaker the howling stops . But the sensitivity is reduced and also I think that to eliminate the mains noise I need to eliminate the ground loops . How do I eliminate ground loop ?
Also Can i use a simple op amp like 741 c to eliminate the noise where the inputs are a scaled version of the output and the preamp input

[image]

[image]

Comment: Howling = get a wind screen. Which will reduce sensitivity.

Comment: So how do I eliminate it

Comment: Are talking about feedback when you say "howling"? You can eliminate it by moving either the mike or the speaker to a different room.

Answer (score 1):

> But i am still getting acoustic howling. What can I do to prevent it
>   dynamically.

I'm going to assume you mean feedback squeal, and you have it if you can stop it by blocking the mic. If that's what you have, you MUST isolate the speaker sound from the microphone. At the least, you point the speaker and the mic in opposite directions. Depending on sensitivities, you may need to put some sort of acoustic shield between the two.

> Also I want to increase the sensitivity to the extent that when I rub
>   my fingers in front of the electret mic the speaker should be able to
>   play it .

This will just make your feedback worse. Plus, it's not likely that a cheap electret mic will have the dynamic range to sense what you want.

> also I think that to eliminate the mains noise I need to eliminate the
>   ground loops . How do I eliminate ground loop ?

You don't have a ground loop. You're just picking up 60 Hz noise. You need to learn about shielding, not ground loops. As a first step, put both circuits on the same breadboard. It's possible that the big loop of wires which connect the two boards is serving as an antenna. In general, keep all of your leads as short as possible. Plus, as long as you put, say, a 10 uF capacitor (with the other lead to ground) on both the 386 Vcc and the 7805 output you can use a single battery.

> Also Can i use a simple op amp like 741 c to eliminate the noise where
>   the inputs are a scaled version of the output and the preamp input

I'm not quite sure what you mean, but you must not, under any circumstances, use a 741 in this circuit. 741s are not well-suited to low power voltage circuits such as your single 9 volt batteries. What do you mean "the noise"? How do you know you have noise? What is it like? Why is it objectionable?

Comment: dual noise cancellation was a great concept, I wonder if it could work in his case?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting acoustic feedback (which is what we assume when you say "howling") then congratulations, your circuit is working perfectly!

ANY system will generate "howling" if you allow the signal from the speaker to reach the microphone.  That is how audio circuits are supposed to work. You see it any time someone with a microphone wanders in front of the PA speaker. It happens thousands of times every day.

The way to prevent the feedback/howling is to ISOLATE the microphone from the acoustic field of the speaker.  Simple as that.

Comment: But how do i increase the sensitivity ?